# How to setup Telegram Web Client?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, telegram

I am trying to build a Telegram web client using React. I looked through the Telegram API documentation and found nothing for JavaScript/TypeScript. Then after a lot of digging through existing Telegram web clients and a ton of googling, I got two options Airgram and GramJS. I read through the documentation of GramJS and it said,

> Click on Create application at the end. Remember that your **API hash is secret** and Telegram won’t let you revoke it. Don’t post it anywhere!

And on the same page,

```
const client = new TelegramClient(stringSession, apiId, apiHash, { connectionRetries: 5 });
```

In my case, this line runs on the client browser so I would have to deliver the API ID and API Hash to the client while keeping them secret. How can I do this? Or am I missing something here?

The situation with Airgram is also the same. Docs on [GitHub](https://github.com/airgram/airgram/blob/118f9c7438920f091a13a460fd41ff09896ce7d9/examples/webpack-config/src/App.ts#L5),

```
const airgram = new Airgram({
  apiId,
  apiHash,
  jsLogVerbosityLevel,
  logVerbosityLevel
})
```

---

Just to add to it I am open to using any other libraries other than Airgram and GramJS that provide the needed functionality.

What I want is a Telegram Client, **not Telegram Bot**, I need to let the user log in to his personal account with OTP and 2FA password ( if it exists ).

---

[Airgram Home Page](https://airgram.netlify.app/)

[GramJS Home Page](https://painor.gitbook.io/gramjs/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where do you store third-party API ApiKey that you use in your javascript web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50948555/where-do-you-store-third-party-api-apikey-that-you-use-in-your-javascript-web-ap)

Comment: This won't work in my case since I am running without a backend.

Comment: There is nothing in your question indicating this. But you are serving your HTML and other assets from somewhere, yes?

Comment: Yes, that is a static hosting. What I want is I want to use the Airgram library on my front end.

Comment: What did you do for this case?

Comment: Still looking for a solution, It was a side project.